# How do I add an image on hover. In a list. *then* style it afterwords

Tags: css, html-lists

In my list. Im trying to add an image. Beside to the right of the names on the nav bar. Below you can see a pic of what Im working with, its Photoshoped. Since I dont know how to code it atm.

On hover, Id like it to change.

I tried :

ul li: hover {  image: url(images/etc.jpg) ;   }

And even if that worked, how would I style the sucker...This is getting too complicated. remember Jedi's. This is my first site.

[image]

Here's the jsfiddle:

```css
.left-nav-box {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #0B88D2; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;   
    height: 1500px;
    margin: 0px;
    position: relative;
    width: 225px;
    
}

.left-nav-box:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;   
    height: 1500px;
    margin: 0px;
    opacity: .95;
    width: 225px;
}


#logo-image {
    border: 2px solid #0B88D2;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.left-nav-box img.logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.left-nav-box img.top:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}




.left-nav-box ul {
    padding: 0px 5px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 168px;
    position: relative;
    top: 160px;
}

.left-nav-box ul li{
    border: 1px solid #0B88D2;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #2B5772;
    font-family: 'segoe ui', 'lucida sans unicode', 'lucida grande',       lucida, sans-serif;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 5px 5px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    width: 198px;

}
.left-nav-box ul li:hover {
    border: 1px solid #0B88D2;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px #0B88D2;
    color: #2B5772;
    font-family: 'segoe ui', 'lucida sans unicode', 'lucida grande',       lucida, sans-serif;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 5px 5px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    width: 168px;
}


.left-nav-box ul li:nth-child(1):hover {
/*border-bottom: 5px solid red;*/
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px red;
  font-family: 'segoe ui', 'lucida sans unicode', 'lucida grande',       lucida, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: #EE0060;

}

#tumblr01 {
 border: 1px solid green; 
    text-align: center;
     position: relative;
    top: 160px;
    }
```

```html
<section id="background-wrapper">
    
    <div class="left-nav-box">
       
      <img src="http://unawakened.net/images/intro.jpg" class="bottom logo" width="180">
            <img src="http://unawakened.net/images/intro.jpg" class="top logo" width="180">
        
    <ul>
        <li>Record</li>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Art & Media</li>
        <li>Archive</li>
        <li>Forums</li>
        <li>Social</li>
        <li>Sign Up</li>
        <li>Contact Us</li>
    </ul>
   
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
  
 
    
     
    </div>
```

Comment: check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33485042/changing-link-image-on-hover#comment54755222_33485042

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a jsfiddle for the code below for your reference: https://jsfiddle.net/5ccusmh9/

Below is the code added, and you only need to replace those borders with your background image like `background:url("link")`

```
.left-nav-box ul li {
    position: relative;
}

.left-nav-box ul li:hover:after {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 10px;
    bottom:0;
    height: 20px;

    // replace theses borders
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid #303030;

    content:"";
}
```

Comment: Where would I put the image tag of the button Im trying to add though?

Comment: Did you leave content blank so I could do somethign like this -->   content:img url("images/nav-button-01.gif")  

?

Comment: Here is the updated one: https://jsfiddle.net/5ccusmh9/1/
You don't need image tag as we are using background image in the :after class. The content in :after is normally for the text, that's why I leave it empty there. Sorry that I reply late as I just got home from work :)

Comment: SNIPE! Thanks man, that helps alot. Should I re-edit this for future users? What in the header did it sound like I was asking and was everything set up to be stacked?

Comment: Not sure how to phrase it to make it sound more generic and informative, but glad that I can help.

Comment: FYI, another answer that ralph.m post would work as well, if you don't need two background images for the same li tag.

Comment: Or if you did, you could look into using a "sprite",  single image with both states, positioned differently depending on hover state.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea would be something like this:

```
ul li:hover {background: url(images/etc.jpg) no-repeat 100% 50%;}
```

That will make the image/icon appear to the far right of the `li` on hover. Mind you, the ideal is to load the image in the browser before hovering so there's no delay, but that's a slightly different issue.

Comment: hmmm...And where would I begin to load? I guess I can always bug my brother